# How to use IN Operator inside Where Condition in Linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I need a help to how to use IN Operator in linq ,

Here is my Code:

```
  achieved =grouped.Key.SMCode=="HETAL1"? 
 grouped.AsEnumerable().Where(x => (x.SalesManCode=="HETAL1"||x.SalesManCode=="BAIJU") &&
 x.OrderType == "Sales Invoice" && x.IsFromService==true).Sum(m => m.OrderValue):0
```

Here i need the value for both `Salesmancode` `baiju` and `hetal1` ,but now i got value only for `hetal1`

i dont know , how to use IN operator in linq

pls help me to get the values of both salesmancode

Answer (score 0):

Please try as shown below.

```
 achieved =(grouped.Key.SMCode=="HETAL1" || grouped.Key.SMCode=="BAIJU") ? 
 grouped.AsEnumerable().Where(x => (x.SalesManCode=="HETAL1"||x.SalesManCode=="BAIJU") &&
 x.OrderType == "Sales Invoice" && x.IsFromService==true).Sum(m => m.OrderValue):0
```